# Selecting value of column based on the values in another column, then applying the value at each row in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, multiple-columns

I have to calculate the value of S, which has the formula as: **S = (25400/CN) − 254**

the CN value which I have to choose will depend on the amc_active condition viz 1, 2 and 3.
if amc_active condition at 'index 0 or 1st row' is 1 then I have to choose the CN value from column cn1 i.e 47

and if the amc_active is 3, then I have to choose CN value as 95 from cn3 column in the 4th row and so on..

```
     cn1         cn2     cn3     amc_active
0     47         56       78         1
1     55         61       87         2
2     36         67       73         1
3     42         84       95         3

... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
17410   42       84       96         3
17411   48       81       85         1
17412   55       59       82         1
17413   57       86       93         2
17414   36       87       91         2
```

for doing so, I am using else if condition

```
    if (df_col_all_merged['amc_active'] == 1):
        cn_for_s = df_col_all_merged['cn1']
    elif (df_col_all_merged['amc_active'] == 2):
        cn_for_s = df_col_all_merged['cn2']
    elif (df_col_all_merged['amc_active'] == 3):
        cn_for_s = df_col_all_merged['cn3']
```

but getting the error as

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-43-40c3b3817474> in <module>
----> 1 if (df_col_all_merged['amc_active'] == 1):
      2     cn_for_s = df_col_all_merged['cn1']
      3 elif (df_col_all_merged['amc_active'] == 2):
      4     cn_for_s = df_col_all_merged['cn2']
      5 elif (df_col_all_merged['amc_active'] == 3):

~\Anaconda3\envs\geocube\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in __nonzero__(self)
   1327 
   1328     def __nonzero__(self):
-> 1329         raise ValueError(
   1330             f"The truth value of a {type(self).__name__} is ambiguous. "
   1331             "Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."

ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

and from this

```
def select_cn(df_col_all_merged):
    result = cn_for_s
    if (df_col_all_merged['amc_active'] == 1):
        cn_for_s = df_col_all_merged['cn1']
    elif (df_col_all_merged['amc_active'] == 2):
        cn_for_s = df_col_all_merged['cn2']
    elif (df_col_all_merged['amc_active'] == 3):
        cn_for_s = df_col_all_merged['cn3']
    return result

df_col_all_merged['s_mm'] = (25400/select_cn(df_col_all_merged)) - 254
```

the error is

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnboundLocalError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-54-df43eddeac39> in <module>
----> 1 df_col_all_merged['s_mm'] = (num_const/select_cn(df_col_all_merged)) - dev_const

<ipython-input-51-7405a6dd24db> in select_cn(df_col_all_merged)
      1 def select_cn(df_col_all_merged):
----> 2     result = cn_for_s
      3     if (df_col_all_merged['amc_active'] == 1):
      4         cn_for_s = df_col_all_merged['cn1']
      5     elif (df_col_all_merged['amc_active'] == 2):

UnboundLocalError: local variable 'cn_for_s' referenced before assignment
```

How to rectify this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use numpy's fancy indexing:

```
# get the values of `cn*` columns
cn_123 = df_col_all_merged[["cn1", "cn2", "cn3"]].to_numpy()

# index into it as "(row_index, amc_active_value-1)"
cn = cn_123[np.arange(len(df_col_all_merged)),
            df.amc_active-1]

# perform the formula
df_col_all_merged["s_mm"] = (25400/cn) - 254
```

where we index each row with the index from `amc_active` (but minus 1 since 0-indexed),

to get

```
       cn1  cn2  cn3  amc_active        s_mm
0       47   56   78           1  286.425532
1       55   61   87           2  162.393443
2       36   67   73           1  451.555556
3       42   84   95           3   13.368421
17410   42   84   96           3   10.583333
17411   48   81   85           1  275.166667
17412   55   59   82           1  207.818182
17413   57   86   93           2   41.348837
17414   36   87   91           2   37.954023
```

---

Alternatively, there is `np.select` in lieu of multiple if-elif's:

```
# form the conditions & corresponding choices
conditions = [df.amc_active.eq(1), df.amc_active.eq(2), df.amc_active.eq(3)]
choices = [df.cn1, df.cn2, df.cn3]

# select so
cn = np.select(conditions, choices)

# formula
df_col_all_merged["s_mm"] = (25400/cn) - 254
```

But due to convenient structure of `df.amc_active` this may not be the best. (also you may omit the last condition & choice and give it as the default to `np.select`, i.e., as an "else").

Comment: Hii Mustafa, in there is index error in 2nd line of your solution, IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices,     cn = cn_123[np.arange(len(df_col_all_merged)), df_col_all_merged.amc_active-1]

Comment: hi @AbhilashSinghChauhan, Then `amc_active` is not an integer column but strings perhaps; so please try `cn_123[np.arange(len(df_col_all_merged)), df_col_all_merged.amc_active.astype(int)-1]`

Comment: now it is showing ValueError: Cannot convert non-finite values (NA or inf) to integer

Answer (score 0):

Use [`DataFrame.melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) for alternative for [lookup](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#indexing-lookup):

```
df1 = df.melt('amc_active', ignore_index=False)

CN = df1.loc['cn' + df1['amc_active'].astype(str) == df1['variable'], 'value']
df['new'] = (25400/CN) - 254
print (df)
       cn1  cn2  cn3  amc_active         new
0       47   56   78           1  286.425532
1       55   61   87           2  162.393443
2       36   67   73           1  451.555556
3       42   84   95           3   13.368421
17410   42   84   96           3   10.583333
17411   48   81   85           1  275.166667
17412   55   59   82           1  207.818182
17413   57   86   93           2   41.348837
17414   36   87   91           2   37.954023
```

Comment: Hiii @jazrael, thanks for the reply, your answer seems right but , CN = df1.loc['cn' + df1['amc_active'].astype(str) == df1['variable'], 'value']
print(CN) in my case I am getting empty series, hence the value in column df['new'] is empty/np.nan

Comment: @AbhilashSinghChauhan - What is `print (df.columns.tolist())` ?

Comment: The output for, print (df_col_all_merged.columns.tolist()) is  [ 'amc_active', 'cn1', 'cn2', 'cn3', 'new']

Comment: actually the 2nd line returns empty series, that's why its not generating any output in 'new' column, on printing,  print(CN) the output is Series([], Name: value, dtype: object)

Comment: @AbhilashSinghChauhan - One idea. If use `df1['cols'] = 'cn' + df1['amc_active'].astype(str)` and then check `print (df1[['cols','variable']])` are values same per rows?

Comment: Now i got it, actually it is adding decimal to the column that's why the value are not being matched,                                                                                                   
           amc_active  variable value   cols
0             1.0  point_id     1  cn1.0
1             1.0  point_id     2  cn1.0
2             1.0  point_id     3  cn1.0

Comment: output for df1['cols'] is cn1.0 and cn2.0 etc